# Calling a classes method from same classes property syntax? PHP

Tags: php, oop

In php reading from here

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

It says,

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().

I have a class and call its methods like below (as I cannot do what it says above!!),

```
$router = new RouterCore();
$method = $router->method;
$controller = new $router->controller();
$controller->$method();
```

What is the syntax for doing what is stated above when both of the class name and the method name exist as properties of another class? I have tried what is below;

```
$router = new RouterCore();
new ($router->controller())->$router->method(); // no go
new $router->controller()->$router->method(); // no go
new ($router->controller()->$router->method()); // no go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not following the syntax from the documentation.

`new ($router->controller())->$router->method();`

is not the same as

`(new $router->controller())->$router->method();`

In the first instance you are trying to perform `new` on the result of `method()`, however the second instance creates a new object from the result of `controller()` and then calls it's method.

Even then `$router` is not going to be a property of the controller, you need to evaluate `$router->method()` first and then use that as the method name.

I suspect what you actually want is

`(new $router->controller())->{$router->method()}();`

Comment: Thank you what I wanted was very close to what you said it was, `(new $this->controller())->{$this->method}();`, will accept when I can, was a very simple mistake to make had me stumped for about half an hour, the joy of programming :p

Comment: Is there any documentation on using the curly braces I have never seen it done before and would like to read up on it?

Comment: @Griff Sure it's hidden in the [String documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) under variable parsing.